# iOS: Threading solution needed for audio processing

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperationqueue, nsnotificationcenter

I am monitoring the microphone in a remoteIO render callback.

I run a simple algorithm to detect whether an audible signal is detected.

If it is, I start to record into a buffer, until again silence.

Once silence is again detected, I need to tell my app that there is a buffer of sound ready for processing.  The app will then perform the processing.

It is essential this is done on a different thread! (the remoteIO render callback thread cannot be blocked, it is a real-time thread and it would stutter the system).

I naïvely assumed I could send an NSNotification from my render callback and it would get picked up on a different thread. But this doesn't happen! It executes on the SAME thread.

What is a tidy way to accomplish this?

My feeling is I should probably spawn a separate thread.  Even doing the processing on the main thread seems a bit glitchy... it might take a quarter of the second also, which would be enough to cause some UX artefact.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a similar thing, the 'simple' answer is I create a serial dispatch queue, then in the audio unit render callback I grab the data and use dispatch_async to pass the new audio data to the serial queue. I use the secondary queue as audio units require you spend as little time as possible in the callback - also you shouldn't malloc memory or generate interrupts and such.

here lockData and unlockData grab pre-allocated NSMutableData objects and store then in a locked/unlocked array.

// in your init method

```
self.captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioCaptureQueue", NULL);
```

in the render callback:

```
__block NSMutableData * audiodata = [audioIO lockData];

status = AudioUnitRender(audioIO.audioUnit, 
            ioActionFlags, 
            inTimeStamp, 
            inBusNumber, 
                     inNumberFrames, 
                     &auBufferList);

dispatch_async(audioIO.captureQueue, ^{
    [audioIO.sampleCaptureDelegate audioComponent:audioIO 
                  hasSampleBuffer:audiodata];

        [audioIO unlockData:audiodata];
});
```

In the serial queue is where I do all the data processing on the audio data, then when the serial queue detects something its looking for it can use

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kAPPAudioQueueDidDetect 
                                                            object:nil];
    });
```

The dispatch_get_main_queue means it is executed on the main thread, so you can do UI updates and such!

Comment: Isn't this going to stall the thread while [audioIO lockData] waits to acquire the lock?

Comment: Its not really a 'lock' the two functions lock and unlock simply move a pointer from one array to another so we know which blocks have usable data in them and which can be reused. I haven't pasted the code since I didn't think it was necessary, but it is a standard 'lock free' ring buffer